# vim does not pause after executing mapped command in .vimrc

Tags: c++, vim

I'm mapping the F8 key in `.vimrc` so that it builds + executes a `.cpp` file. The command I use is

```
map <F8> :w <CR> :!g++ -std=c++11 % -o %< && ./%< <CR>
```

The problem is that after I press F8, the output appears but `vim` is not waiting for ENTER after displaying "press ENTER to continue" (so basically the output of the program briefly appears then immediately disappears). If I remove the `<CR>` from above, then I have to manually hit ENTER after pressing F8. Is there any way of making `vim` to wait for pressing the ENTER key after executing the mapped command above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a *trailing space* after `<CR>` in your mapping. That would acknowledge the *hit-enter* prompt.

---

You can use plugins like my [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966) to detect and [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) to (automatically) remove trailing whitespace. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

---

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: many thanks! yes, that was the issue, now realized that space was eating up the input buffer.

Comment: It is fairly simple to show and delete whitespace.  To delete it, just do this: `:%s/\s\+$//e`.  And to show whitespace, just do this: `:set listchars+=tail:- ` I don't really see why a plugin is necessary.